# Mask/Background tool in Microstation?

Tags: microstation

Using Microstation V8i (2012 version i believe) and can't seem to find an equivalent tool to Autocad's "background" for text. Is there a mask or background setting I can apply to certain texts?

Edit: I found another solution. Using the "field" tool to select an area to mask, usually using the box method, and then clipping the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Element->Text Styles. You can create new text style with Fill Color and Background Border using MS Background color.

There is more information connected with that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdlGFZCN6o4

Comment: thanks, i had seen someone mention the Text Styles option but had trouble locating it in Microstation